# Get "holes" in dates in MogoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that stores data for each hour since 2011.
For example:

```
{ 
    "dateEntity" : ISODate("2011-01-01T08:00:00Z"), 
    "price" : 0.3
}

{ 
    "dateEntity" : ISODate("2011-01-01T09:00:00Z"), 
    "price" : 0.35
}
```

I'd like to know if there are "holes" in that dates. For example, a missing entry at a hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no gaps-marking aggregator in Mongodb.
I have checked if it's possible to write an own gaps-aggregator for Mongodb basing on Javascript functions in Map-Reduce pipelines by creating a time raster in the first map stage and then mapping it to its corresponding values, but database reads are discouraged while mapping and reducing, so it would be bad design. So, it is not possible to achieve this with Mongodb-own instruments.
I think, there are two possible solutions.

## Solution one: Use a driver like the Java driver

I suggest you could use an idiomatic driver like the Java driver for your Mongodb data and create a raster of hours like in the Test provided.

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class HourGapsTest {

    @Test
    public void testHourValues() {
        String host = "127.0.0.1:27017";
        ServerAddress addr = new ServerAddress(host);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(addr);
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("sotest").getCollection("hourhole");

        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2011, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0);
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(2011, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0);

        List<LocalDateTime> allHours = new ArrayList<>();

        for (LocalDateTime hour = start; hour.isBefore(end); hour = hour.plusHours(1L)) {
            allHours.add(hour);
        }

        List<LocalDateTime> gaps = new ArrayList<>();

        for (LocalDateTime hour : allHours) {
            BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("dateEntity", new Date(hour.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()));
            if (!collection.find(filter).iterator().hasNext()) {
                gaps.add(hour);
            }
        }
        gaps.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

## Solution two: Use a timeseries database

However, timeseries databases like Kairosdb provide this functionality. Consider storing these time-value data in a timeseries database.

Comment: Thank you for that really helpful answer. I will see to use a timeseries database such as Axibase wich can be (I think) easily used with Spring boot (my project is a Spring batch job).

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with that. I'm looking forward on using spring boot too.